# Unable to import Schedule module in Python3.5.2

Tags: import, pip, python-3.5, schedule, python-venv

I have one virtual environment. I installed schedule module using pip. It has installed successfully. In python default IDE it work fine. But When I import it in a python script, it says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'schedule'
```

Python version: 3.5.2
schedule version: 0.6.0
I can locate the module in site-packages.

Comment: your IDE and your script are probably using different python interpreters, check that the output of `print(sys.executable)` and `print(sys.path)` are the same when executed in your IDE and when you are running your script

Comment: Yeah. That was the problem. My package was in .local/lib , and interpreter was using packages from usr/lib.